# Windows 10 UEFI does not allow Grub boot (Kali install)

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I am trying to get dual-boot to work. I followed these instructions exactly: https://docs.kali.org/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows
I have also tried manually setting up the partitions (i am using 30 GB, which should be enough)

I have an Acer Aspire E5-574 Laptop, which came with Windows 10 and UEFI, and when I run the install from my Live USB, everything seems to work fine, I set up a password, connect to an internet, and it says it is installing Grub, followed by a screen telling me to unplug the USB and restart to enter Kali linux. I do this, and the only option I get in the F12 boot menu is Windows Boot Manager. The Windows Boot Manager only lets me select either Windows 10 or Memory Diagnostics.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you boot into UEFI for the installation?

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson I am not sure what you mean. I inserted the USB, pressed F12 and selected "USB 32 GB lexer drive"

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson I tried it again, this time doing it from the Windows 10 UEFI menu (accessed by holding shift and pressing restart before logging in). Same results.

Comment: Are you booting it in UEFI or Legacy in BIOS? Go to your UEFI settings and see what mode is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows is not seeing GRUB and it appears that this is a known issue on ACER laptops with Windows 10, rather than a Linux/Kali one.

Try [THIS](https://kaliuefi.blogspot.co.uk/) fix or web search the appropriate equivalent for your BIOS/firmware version.